# How to get the last char of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I need to get the last character of a string.
Say I have "testers" as input string and I want the result to be "s". how can I do that in PHP?

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->end()`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L192) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 1210, accepted):

```
substr("testers", -1); // returns "s"
```

Or, for multibyte strings :

```
mb_substr("multibyte string…", -1); // returns "…"
```

Comment: If you’re using multibyte character encodings like UTF-8, use `mb_substr` (http://php.net/mb_substr) instead.

Comment: so much for my substr($string, strlen($string)-1, 1);. Seems I've taken the LONG way around!

Comment: You only need multibyte string functions if the string is evaluated as binary string. Aka, when php doesn't know the encoding. Otherwise the typical non multibyte  string functions will work just fine.

Comment: Please see Yes Barry's answer. From PHP 8 you can use `str_ends_with()`

Answer (score 97):

```
substr($string, -1)
```

Answer (score 79):

Or by [direct string access](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

```
$string[strlen($string)-1];
```

Note that this doesn't work for multibyte strings. If you need to work with multibyte string, consider using the [`mb_*` string family of functions.](http://php.net/mb_substr)

As of PHP 7.1.0 negative numeric indices are also supported, e.g just `$string[-1];`

Comment: I like this C style answer, I wonder why this has only got this few upvotes.

Comment: @ValentinMercier: Because this is a PHP question, not C.

Comment: I think this is a better solution because it allows you to modify the character, whereas the substr solution given above does not.

Comment: Note that this will throw a notice if the string is empty.

Answer (score 56):

From PHP 7.1 you can do this ([Accepted rfc for negative string offsets](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/negative-string-offsets)):

```
<?php
$silly = 'Mary had a little lamb';
echo $silly[-20];
echo $silly{-6};
echo $silly[-3];
echo $silly[-15];
echo $silly[-13];
echo $silly[-1];
echo $silly[-4];
echo $silly{-10};
echo $silly[-4];
echo $silly[-8];
echo $silly{3}; // <-- this will be deprecated in PHP 7.4
die();
```

I'll let you guess the output.

Also, I added this to [xenonite's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3996393/xenonite) performance code with these results:

> substr() took 7.0334868431091seconds
>
> array access took 2.3111131191254seconds
>
> Direct string access (negative string offsets) took 1.7971360683441seconds

Comment: Thanks for posting benchmarks! If anyone is interested in C# benchmarks for doing the same thing, [this page](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/c-fastest-way-to-check-last-character-of-a-string) is a good read. Directly accessing the last character won out.

Comment: could you explain more about difference between [] and {} in this context?

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda Technically there is no difference between [] and {}. The PHP developers gave the option to use either. For more details see: http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Comment: what is array access and what is direct string access? @RyanNerd
afaik those are 2 same things, no?

Comment: @CT. See Xenonite's answer and benchmarks above. I am using his language for the description of each string access method.

Comment: $string{1} will be deprecated in PHP 7.4 (RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access)

Comment: You missed an `i` out ;)

Comment: It spells `readablilty`. I assume he meant `readability`?  Yes, 5 years later, I was curious lol.

Comment: IMPORTANT: when the string is empty, it will thow an error `PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: -1`. So, check that before.

Answer (score 37):

As of PHP 7.1.0, negative string offsets are also supported.
So, if you keep up with the times, you can access the last character in the string like this:

```
$str[-1]
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff439889f14906749e4eb6328796c354c60f269b)

At the request of a @mickmackusa, I supplement my answer with possible ways of application:

```
<?php

$str='abcdef';
var_dump($str[-2]); // => string(1) "e"

$str[-3]='.';
var_dump($str);     // => string(6) "abc.ef"

var_dump(isset($str[-4]));  // => bool(true)

var_dump(isset($str[-10])); // => bool(false)
```

Comment: Using negative offsets was a technique mentioned years earlier by RyanNerd.  Please post an answer only when you have unique and valuable insights to share.

Comment: @mickmackusa Why did you write it only to me and ignored the multiple variations substr()?

Comment: Nothing personal, I just saw your very short and redundant answer and decided to blow my whistle.  Feel free to whistleblow the other answers if you feel they add no value.  Keep in mind, two answers can suggest the same technique but both be individually valuable because of what is explained.  This is a place of education and empowerment -- adding unique insights to previously offered solutions can be quite valuable to researchers.

Comment: For example, [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52098132/2943403) was posted a month after the same technique was posted.  I was going to write a comment under the earlier answer, but as I typed out all of the information that I wanted to offer, it was obviously too much to sensibly comment.  I posted a new answer and added lots of complimentary insights and background information regarding the technique and included a benchmark.  This is how a non-unique solution can be valuable to researchers.

Comment: This should be marked as answer

Answer (score 18):

I can't leave comments, but in regard to FastTrack's answer, also remember that the line ending may be only single character.  I would suggest

```
substr(trim($string), -1)
```

**EDIT:** *My code below was edited by someone, making it not do what I indicated.  I have restored my original code and changed the wording to make it more clear.*

`trim` (or `rtrim`) will remove *all* whitespace, so if you do need to check for a space, tab, or other whitespace, manually replace the various line endings first:

```
$order = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$string = str_replace($order, '', $string);
$lastchar = substr($string, -1);
```

Answer (score 14):

As of PHP 8 you can now use [`str_ends_with()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-ends-with.php)

```
$string = 'testers';
if (\str_ends_with($string, 's') {
    // yes
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd advise to go for Gordon's solution as it is more performant than substr():

```
<?php 

$string = 'abcdef';
$repetitions = 10000000;

echo "\n\n";
echo "----------------------------------\n";
echo $repetitions . " repetitions...\n";
echo "----------------------------------\n";
echo "\n\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<$repetitions; $i++)
    $x = substr($string, -1);

echo "substr() took " . (microtime(true) - $start) . "seconds\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<$repetitions; $i++)
    $x = $string[strlen($string)-1];

echo "array access took " . (microtime(true) - $start) . "seconds\n";

die();
```

outputs something like

```
 ---------------------------------- 
 10000000 repetitions...
 ----------------------------------

 substr() took 2.0285921096802seconds 
 array access took 1.7474739551544seconds
```

Comment: This should be a comment on Gordon's answer.

Comment: Can confirm this. The longer your string is, the bigger is the performance difference. In my test with 10 characters substr is around 20 % slower

Comment: Not surprising as substr() has the overhead of a function call and the other is "C like" direct string manipulation. BTW I ran this code on PHP 7.1-dev with the results: substr() took 7.090255022049seconds \
array access took 2.3145787715912seconds

Answer (score 4):

Remember, if you have a string which was read as a line from a text file using the `fgets()` function, you need to use `substr($string, -3, 1)` so that you get the actual character and not part of the CRLF (Carriage Return Line Feed).

I don't think the person who asked the question needed this, but for me, I was having trouble getting that last character from a string from a text file so I'm sure others will come across similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can find last character using php many ways like [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

> If you’re using multibyte character encodings like UTF-8, use **mb_substr** instead of **substr**

Here i can show you both example:

```
<?php
    echo substr("testers", -1);
    echo mb_substr("testers", -1);
?>
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32d0797f90f047f73b70967e6c7a595fa9e13297)

Answer (score 1):

A string in different languages including C sharp and PHP is also considered an array of characters.

Knowing that in theory array operations should be faster than string ones you could do,

```
$foo = "bar";


$lastChar = strlen($foo) -1;
echo $foo[$lastChar];

$firstChar = 0;
echo $foo[$firstChar];
```

However, standard array functions like

```
count();
```

will not work on a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use substr() with a negative number for the 2nd argument.`$newstring = substr($string1, -1);`

Comment: Why offer the same solution as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2681810/2915423) more than ten years later?

Answer (score -3):

Siemano, get only php files from selected directory:

```
$dir    = '/home/zetdoa/ftp/domeny/MY_DOMAIN/projekty/project';
$files = scandir($dir, 1);


foreach($files as $file){
  $n = substr($file, -3);
  if($n == 'php'){
    echo $file.'<br />';
  }
}
```