# Check if variable ends with

Tags: php, variables

i have the variable `$uid` 
that always contain a number.
I want to execute different actions depending on how the `$uid` ends.
For example:

```
if(&uid ENDS WITH 2,3 or 4) {echo "Some content"};
else if($uid ENDS WITH 1,5 or 6) {echo "Some other content"};
else if($uid ENDS WITH 7,8,9 or 0) {echo "Some other content"};
```

Nothing comes on my mind how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance for Your time!

Comment: This really is a bad piece of design, I thought code flow based on actual variable name died out in the 70's - why not simply use an array and test on the key

Comment: i agree, im not good at php at all.

Comment: This will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681786/how-to-get-the-last-char-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: Do you want the variable name to end with 2,3.. or the variable value?

Comment: Ok now you have three different ways to do the same thing!

Comment: @popnoodles - all 3 solutions works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $endsWith = substr($uid, -1);
    if (in_array($endsWith, array(2, 3, 4)) echo "something";
    elseif () // ... etc
```

Comment: I tried:
`<?php
$uid = 22;
$endsWith = substr($uid, -1);
    if (in_array($endsWith, array(2, 3, 4)) echo "something";
?>`
and it outputs error:
`syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /var/www/dn/index.php on line 4`
any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

```
$end = substr($uid, -1);
if($end == 2 || $end == 3 || $end == 4){
echo "Some content";
}
else if($end == 1 || $end == 5 || $end == 6){
echo "Some other content";
}
else if($end == 7 || $end == 8 || $end == 9 || $end == 0){
echo "Some other content";
}
```

**Update:** If you know that `$uid` is an integer, you may change the first line to:
`$end = $uid % 10;`

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to swing this cat. Using lots of if/elseif like you have, but that becomes hard to read. You can use `in_array()` which is a good solution, but again you have several if/elseifs.

I prefer to use a switch.

```
$end=substr($uid, -1);

switch ($end){
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        echo "Some content";
        break;
    case 1:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        echo "Some other content";
        break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 0:
        echo "Some other other content";
        break;
}
```