# How to find a string with php?

Tags: php, string, strpos

I have a string: "Tip #123 some random text" and I need to place a `<br />` tag after `#123` so that `some random text` is in a new line.

I could find the `#` with `strpos`, but where do I go from there?

Comment: Take a look at `str_replace()`. Just `#123` to `#123<br />`

Comment: @Rizier123 ok, but what if the string is `#126`, I need to find the full number and how can I do that? So the `#` + following numbers form a string I must find.

Comment: Then you want to use `preg_replace()`. And say that you want `#\d+` instead of hardcoded `#123`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681786/how-to-get-the-last-char-of-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
/**
 * Function to create a dynamic replacement.
 * @param array $match An array with the match of the pattern.
 * @return string The replacement.
 */
function getReplacement($match)
{
    if (isset($match[0])) {
        return $match[0].'<br/>';
    }
}

//the value to replace specific parts.
$string = 'Tip #1 some #12 random #123 text #1234, an #12345 example #123456';

//replace all parts starting with '#' and three numbers following.
echo preg_replace_callback('/#[0-9]+/', 'getReplacement', $string);
```

A working example you can find here: https://3v4l.org/RNmkj

Comment: Thanks! Can you please show a way for dynamic ammount of numbers after the `#` ? So that there can be #1 #12 #123 #1234 and any number after it

Comment: changed code and added `+` for one ore more numbers after `#`.