# Checking during array iteration, if the current element is the last element

Tags: php, arrays

Please help me to translate this pseudo-code to real php code:

```
 foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
    if ( THIS IS NOT THE LAST ELEMENT IN THE ARRAY)
        doSomething();
```

Edit: the array may have numerical or string keys

Comment: Why not use `for` loop for `count($arr) - 1` iterations?

Comment: If you have mixed keys, how do you determine which key is the last item? If you want it as the last item added to the array, then there should be some data to indicate a time stamp.

Comment: definition for last: by the inner order of the array. Which is identical to saying the last element that the foreach loop will pick

Comment: Related: [How to get last key in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2348205/2943403)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

you can use PHP's [end()](https://www.php.net/end)

```
$array = array('a' => 1,'b' => 2,'c' => 3);
$lastElement = end($array);
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    echo $v . '<br/>';
    if($v == $lastElement) {
         // 'you can do something here as this condition states it just entered last element of an array'; 
    }
}
```

**Update1**

as pointed out by @Mijoja the above could will have problem if you have same value multiple times in array. below is the fix for it.

```
$array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 2);
//point to end of the array
end($array);
//fetch key of the last element of the array.
$lastElementKey = key($array);
//iterate the array
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if($k == $lastElementKey) {
        //during array iteration this condition states the last element.
    }
}
```

**Update2**

I found solution by @onteria_ to be better then what i have answered since it does not modify arrays internal pointer, i am updating the answer to match his answer.

```
$array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 2);
// Get array keys
$arrayKeys = array_keys($array);
// Fetch last array key
$lastArrayKey = array_pop($arrayKeys);
//iterate array
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if($k == $lastArrayKey) {
        //during array iteration this condition states the last element.
    }
}
```

Thank you @onteria_

**Update3**

As pointed by @CGundlach PHP 7.3 introduced `array_key_last` which seems much better option if you are using PHP >= 7.3

```
$array = array('a' => 1,'b' => 2,'c' => 3);
$lastKey = array_key_last($array);
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    echo $v . '<br/>';
    if($k == $lastKey) {
         // 'you can do something here as this condition states it just entered last element of an array'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This will have problems if you have the same value multiple times in the array

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Just found this answer and while implementing your solution I noticed that since PHP 7.3 there is now the function `array_key_last`, which also returns the last key of an array without affecting the internal pointer: https://secure.php.net/array_key_last. Would simplify your solution even more :)

Comment: @CGundlach that's good to know. Will update the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 27):

This always does the trick for me

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   if (end(array_keys($array)) == $key)
       // Last key reached
}
```

Edit 30/04/15

```
$last_key = end(array_keys($array));
reset($array);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  if ( $key == $last_key)
      // Last key reached
}
```

To avoid the E_STRICT warning mentioned by @Warren Sergent

```
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
$last_key = end($array_keys);
```

Comment: @Pierce to give you a hint: this was answered 3 and a half years after the accepted answer, plus if you have a 1000 items in your array, you will call "end" 1000 times and "array_keys" 1000 times.

Comment: This clearly has performance issues if you are iterating over a large array. My suggestion in that case is to move the end(array_keys($array)) outside the loop. But make sure you reset the array before the iteration.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, under strict mode, end(array_keys($array)) will cause a notice, as "Only variables should be passed by reference" - to correct this, define $array_keys = array_keys($array) and call end() on the $array_keys variable.

Comment: @WarrenSergent, or jou can just use double parenthesis to avoid strict notice, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776017/why-am-i-getting-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-error

Comment: @Danijel Whilst that's true, I wouldn't necessarily rely on suppressing or 'avoiding' the notice. The double parenthesis issue has some interesting discussion here too regarding whether this could be considered a BUG in PHP itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726589/parentheses-altering-semantics-of-function-call-result

Answer (score 15):

```
$myarray = array(
  'test1' => 'foo',
  'test2' => 'bar',
  'test3' => 'baz',
  'test4' => 'waldo'
);

$myarray2 = array(
'foo',
'bar',
'baz',
'waldo'
);

// Get the last array_key
$last = array_pop(array_keys($myarray));
foreach($myarray as $key => $value) {
  if($key != $last) {
    echo "$key -> $value\n";
  }
}

// Get the last array_key
$last = array_pop(array_keys($myarray2));
foreach($myarray2 as $key => $value) {
  if($key != $last) {
    echo "$key -> $value\n";
  }
}
```

Since `array_pop` works on the temporary array created by `array_keys` it doesn't modify the original array at all.

```
$ php test.php
test1 -> foo
test2 -> bar
test3 -> baz
0 -> foo
1 -> bar
2 -> baz
```

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer because it only requires one line for initialization outside the loop.

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer because it doesn't alter the internal pointer of the array you're about to loop over.

Comment: to do the same for the first element `$first = array_shift(array_keys($myarray2));`

Comment: This produces a notice in E_STRICT: Runtime Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: This seems better approach then my answer, updating my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Why not this very simple method:

```
$i = 0; //a counter to track which element we are at
foreach($array as $index => $value) {
    $i++;
    if( $i == sizeof($array) ){
        //we are at the last element of the array
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not?  Because it pointless to call `sizeof()` inside of a loop.  The array's size never changes, so why keep calling a function that returns the count?  More importantly, PHP now has `array_key_last()` which is more direct and is not limited to handling indexed arrays.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, and using SPL iterator maybe just an overkill, but anyway, another solution here:

```
$ary = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 'last');
$ary = new ArrayIterator($ary);
$ary = new CachingIterator($ary);
foreach ($ary as $each) {
    if (!$ary->hasNext()) { // we chain ArrayIterator and CachingIterator
                            // just to use this `hasNext()` method to see
                            // if this is the last element
       echo $each;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution, also quite simple..

```
$array = [...];
$last = count($array) - 1;

foreach($array as $index => $value) 
{
     if($index == $last)
        // this is last array
     else
        // this is not last array
}
```

Comment: This is pretty nice and simple, as long as your array keys have been auto-generated.

Comment: There is no longer a reason to leverage a situationally-dependent technique like this because PHP now has `array_key_last()`.  See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the items are numerically ordered, use the key() function to determine the index of the current item and compare it to the length. You'd have to use next() or prev() to cycle through items in a while loop instead of a for loop:

```
$length = sizeOf($arr);
while (key(current($arr)) != $length-1) {
    $v = current($arr); doSomething($v); //do something if not the last item
    next($myArray); //set pointer to next item
}
```

Comment: Will not work for non numerical, or otherwise non strictly ordered items

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach using `array_keys` function to get the keys and get only **first** key `[0]` of reversed array which is the *last key*.

```php
$array = array('a' => 1,'b' => 2,'c' => 3);
$last_key = array_keys(array_reverse($array, true))[0];
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   if ($last_key !== $key)
       // THIS IS NOT THE LAST ELEMENT IN THE ARRAY doSomething();
}
```

**NOTE**: `array_reverse` reverse array take two arguments first array we want be reversed and second parameter true, to reverse the array and **preserves the order of keys**.

Comment: This is FAR too much processing versus merely calling `array_key_last()`.