# Why am I getting "Only variables should be passed by reference" error?

Tags: php, variables, pass-by-reference

Check out this code:

```
$last = end($p = explode('/', $someString));
```

Getting this notice:

> Only variables should be passed by reference

I'm really confused because `$p` is a variable.

Comment: can you show more code? is `$someString` an array?

Comment: @demonking: Why is more code necessary?

Comment: sorry my mistake, remove the `$p =` from your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4636166/1255289)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function end() expects a real variable and not a function returning an array, but if you put the function return inside double parentheses PHP does not report a strict standards notice:

```
$last = end( ( explode( '/', $someString ) ) );
```

Comment: that's better :) I hope it's not a bug

Comment: Although I'd not recommend suppressing warnings and notices, this is pretty interesting. It apparently works exactly as you describe, Danijel. Is this behavior documented somewhere in the php manual? I can find no reference whatsoever.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726589/parentheses-altering-semantics-of-function-call-result) is an interesting discussion about this topic, but it seems that nobody knows for sure whether this behavior is a feature or a bug.

Comment: @Jirka It's documented, when you're using `$b = ($a = 5)`, at the second side is not an expression anymore, you made it a variable.

Answer (score 12):

`end()` expects a variable, not a reference. In your exemple `$p = explode('/', $someString)` is not a variable, it's an assignment. As the [documentation](http://www.php.net/end) said:

> This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.

You should do this instead:

```
$p = explode('/', $someString);
$last = end($p);
```

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious that I'm not passing a return value, but `$p` which is a variable...

Comment: @thelolcat It is not so obvious. If I am not mistaken, the returned value is used, then the assignment is made. Check out my edit.

Comment: Your edit is misguided. `echo $a = $b` would print `2` either way: the OP expects it to mean the same as `$a = $b; echo $a`, whereas you're saying it should mean `echo $b; $a = $b`, but both of those are equivalent. (And in fact, I think it actually means `$a = $b; echo $b` -- but again, equivalent.)

Comment: @ruakh You are right, it doesn't make sense... I will remove it. Thanks.

Comment: Well I still don't get it. I specifically assigned the return value of explode to a variable so I don't see that notice, and I'm still seeing it

Comment: @thelolcat Actually I don't understand the underlying reason either. If you follow the documentation precisely, `$p = explode('/', $someString)` is not a variable. I am currently researching why the reference is used as a parameter instead of the variable itself.

Comment: @MathieuImbert You are right. It is not using variable, because `$p = explode('/', $someString)` is a STATEMENT, which returns not the reference, but the VALUE itself. I.e. `$a = $b = 'x'`, means to return to `$a` not a reference of `$b`, but it's VALUE. In anoter case, that OP is asking, `$a` will depend on `$b`s value (changes, applied to `$b`s value will affect the value of `$a`), which is not obvious. By default, they should be COMPLETELY INDEPENDENT, unless the value is an object, because objects are implicitly passed by reference.

Comment: @MathieuImbert in any case, multiple assignment returns value, not a variable, so there is no way (yet) for PHP to create a reference by approaches like OP suggests.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're doing assignment to a function, and the value being passed to $last is actually the result of the function, not $p. And, `explode` returns a reference to a variable.

Do it in two lines:

```
$p = explode('/', $someString);
$last = end($p);
```

There's no reason to be assigning to $p inside the function call of end(), unless you're using $p later. And for stylistic clarity I'd suggest doing it in two steps anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

Functions like `end()` will affect the variable and change their values if they're supposed to, and as all of us know, it means Pass by Reference! But this kind of passing needs *tendency*, we can't just push things to them without any care!

On giving `Only variables should be passed by reference` actually the problem is not that variable, however you did it when tried `end($p = explode('/', $someString));` but the kind of passing it to the function, because you're not allowed to make a reference on that on calling `end()`, ***you made an [Expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) as an input not a variable.***

***Expressions***:

> PHP takes expressions much further, in the same way many other
>   languages do. PHP is an expression-oriented language, in the sense
>   that almost everything is an expression. Consider the example we've
>   already dealt with, $a = 5. It's easy to see that there are two values
>   involved here, the value of the integer constant 5, and the value of
>   $a which is being updated to 5 as well. **But the truth is that there's
>   one additional value involved here, and that's the value of the
>   assignment itself. The assignment itself evaluates to the assigned
>   value, in this case 5. In practice, it means that $a = 5, regardless
>   of what it does, is an expression with the value 5.** Thus, writing
>   something like $b = ($a = 5) is like writing $a = 5; $b = 5; (a
>   semicolon marks the end of a statement). Since assignments are parsed
>   in a right to left order, you can also write $b = $a = 5.

That error is just a kind of strict error at your case and not a fatal one! well you know that PHP is a strict programming language. But you can disable them manually. That doesn't change the result.

Some examples on this issue:

```
function foo($a)
{
    return ++$a;
};
$b = 1;
echo foo(&$b);
```

**Error**:

`Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed; If you would like to pass argument by reference, modify the declaration of foo()` since PHP 5.3.0

**Or**

```
function foo(&$a)
{
    return ++$a;
};
echo foo($b = 1); // output: 2
```

**We've seen it before** `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`