# Wordpress: How to add commas in this get_the_terms function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this function:

```
// Get terms for post
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'skills');
if($terms != null) {
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        echo $term->name . ", ";
        unset($term);
    }
}
```

However I see the terms as term1, term2, term3, (with also a comma at the end), how can I show the terms with commas but without that comma when is not necessary?

Comment: Test for the end of the array. If you're not at the end, use the comma, otherwise, skip it. Here's an example that should be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092054/checking-during-array-iteration-if-the-current-element-is-the-last-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of echoing all the variables *during* your loop, you should store them all to an array and then use the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to echo them all with the formatting you desire.

```
// Get terms for post
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'skills');
if($terms != null) {
    $output = array();
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $output[] = $term->name;
        unset($term);
    }
    echo implode(", ", $output)
}
```

---

Don't want to use an array or variable? There is another solution. Just check if you are currently on the very last element in the array during your loop.

```
// Get terms for post
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'skills');
if($terms != null) {
    end($terms);
    $endKey = key($terms);
    foreach($terms as $key => $term) {
        echo $key != $endKey? $term->name.", " : $term->name;
        unset($term);
    }
}
```

I added `$key` to the foreach loop so you can compare against that. You can get the final key of the array by doing [`end($array)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) and then using [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) to get the actual key.

Comment: @MiguelZafra glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use array use following:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'skills');
$string = "";
if($terms != null) {
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $string .= $term->name . ", ";
    unset($term);
}
}

echo trim($string, ", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rtrim. (from php.net : Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string)

```
// Get terms for post
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'skills');
if($terms != null) {
    $stringFinal = "";
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $stringFinal = $term->name . ", ";
    }
    $stringFinal = rtrim($stringFinal, ', ')
}
echo $stringFinal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Omitting all checks, this can be reduced to one line.

```
// Get terms for post
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'skills');

echo implode(", ", array_map(function($T) {return is_a($T, 'WP_Term') ? $T->name : false; }, $terms ))
```

Works like array_column but with object