# How to remove the last comma from foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to remove the last comma(,) from foreach loop in php with the following code

```
<?php

foreach ($snippet_tags as $tag_data) {
    $tags_id = $tag_data->tag_id;
    $tagsdata = $this->Constant_model->getDataOneColumn('tags', 'id', $tags_id);
    $tag_name=$tagsdata[0]->tag_name;
?>

<a href="<?= base_url() ?>tags/<?php echo $tag_name; ?>"><?php echo $tag_name; ?></a> ,       

<?php } 
?>
```

Right I am getting result like

> Hello, How, sam,

But i wants to remove the last comma

Comment: @u_mulder Did you properly check? my question related to the question what you linked?

Comment: Why wouldn't what @u_mulder suggested work?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I agreed!

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's like a hint for OP - __use a search__.

Comment: @u_mulder Better you please give the answer and let us know how its related to the question what you linked to

Comment: @RiggsFolly Should I push the variable in a string array and separate them by comma and again rtrim them?

Comment: Use rtrim function in php

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you give the answer as I am getting array to string conversion error.

Comment: Check accepted answer, this will help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092054/checking-during-array-iteration-if-the-current-element-is-the-last-element you can use last key here, store last key of your array before foreach then check inside the loop if key is equal to stored last key, avoid to add comma other wise add.

Comment: @RiggsFolly With your answer still getting comma after result

Comment: easy solution: save your link in a string and then create an array of links then simply use `implode(' ,' $links_arr)`

Comment: Now getting the result without comma anywhere :(

Comment: check this link also, this is an another solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092054/checking-during-array-iteration-if-the-current-element-is-the-last-element

Comment: @RiggsFolly when i am using .= getting Undefined variable: out error

Comment: replace all your code with this.
`<?php 
$tags = [];
foreach ($snippet_tags as $tag_data) {
    $tags_id = $tag_data->tag_id;
    $tagsdata = $this->Constant_model->getDataOneColumn('tags', 'id', $tags_id);
    $tag_name=$tagsdata[0]->tag_name;
    $tag = "<a href=".base_url()."tags/{$tag_name}>{$tag_name}</a>";
    $tags[] = $tag;}
    $tags = implode(' ,' $tags);
    echo $tags;
?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing the HTML in a simple string variable and then using `rtrim()` on the resulting string before outputting it this should remove the final `,` from the string

```
<?php
$out = '';

foreach ($snippet_tags as $tag_data) {
    $tags_id = $tag_data->tag_id;
    $tagsdata = $this->Constant_model->getDataOneColumn('tags', 'id', $tags_id);
    $tag_name=$tagsdata[0]->tag_name;

    // move inside loop and amend to place in a simple string var
    $out .= '<a href="' . base_url() . 'tags/' . $tag_name . '">' . $tag_name . '</a>,';
?>

echo rtrim($out, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code -

```
<?php
$numItems = count($snippet_tags);
$i = 0;

foreach ($snippet_tags as $tag_data) {
   $tags_id = $tag_data->tag_id;
   $tagsdata = $this->Constant_model->getDataOneColumn('tags', 'id', $tags_id);
   $tag_name=$tagsdata[0]->tag_name;
?>

if(++$i === $numItems) 
   echo "<a href='base_url() ?>tags/<?php echo $tag_name;'> $tag_name</a>";
else echo "<a href='base_url() ?>tags/<?php echo $tag_name;'> $tag_name</a> ,";     

<?php 
} 
?>
```