# Foreach last item gets methode

Tags: php, foreach

Guys I have an array with objects,
I want the last item in the foreach loop do something else then the rest.
How do I archive that?

```
if(sizeof($testDup) > 3){
    } else {
        foreach ($testDup as $d) {  
        }
    }

$test array(3)
    432 => test_id -> 21
    431 => test_id -> 21
    435 => test_id -> 21
```

Comment: You can `count` array then use `foreach ($testDup as $index => $d)` and use last index for what you need

Comment: How would I write that?

Comment: Look my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking during array iteration, if the current element is the last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092054/checking-during-array-iteration-if-the-current-element-is-the-last-element)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini oh But I need to do a methode on an Object. I cant do deleted on int. So how would I do it with that? I have 3 Objects in an Array, want to delete only 2 of them.

Comment: Can you so post array object then we can see structure?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I did so u can see I have 3 test_id with same value, and I just wanna delete 2 of the to keep only one with the value test_id 21

Comment: @SimoneRossaini So would want to use the methode delete only on two of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will process the array of objects and do something else with the last element:

```
    $data = '';
    $arrayWithObjects = array(
        (object)array('test1', 'test2'),
        (object)array('test1', 'test2'),
        (object)array('test1', 'test2'),
    );

    foreach ($arrayWithObjects as $object) {
        // Can't get next in the array, so is last element
        if (!next($arrayWithObjects)) {
            // Process last element
            $data .= $object->{1};
        } else {
            // Process all other elements
            $data .= $object->{0};
        }
    }

    var_dump($data); // "test1test1test2"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the current one with the `end()`:

```
class Test {
    public function __construct(private string $name) {}
    
    public function read(): string {
        return sprintf('%s: hurray', $this->name);
    }
    
    public function readLast():string {
        return sprintf('%s: am I last?', $this->name);
    }
}



$array = [
    new Test('first'),
    new Test('second'),
    new Test('third'),
    new Test('fourth'),
    ];
              
foreach( $array as $object ){
    if($object === end($array)) {
        echo $object->readLast().PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo $object->read().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to checking if the current item is the last one (which the other answers show), you could use [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the start of the array to loop over and then [end()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to get the last element of the array.

```php
$data = [/*...*/]

foreach ($item as array_splice($data, 0, -1, true) {
   $item->foo();
}

if (($item = end($data) !== false) {
    $item->bar();
}
```

In my opinion, this code is easier to read (and metrics like cyclomatic complexity agree) than the nested `if $item === end($data)` check. If the same is true on your specific case will depend on what, exactly is in the loop and how much of it is different.

In addition, if your array is large, this approach may offer (slightly) better performance (but if your array is large and a small performance difference is important, don't take my word for this - benchmark both solutions with read data).

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy: When the loop is finished, you still got the last element!!

```
if (!empty($arr)) {
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        ; // Do something with $item
    }

    // Here you still got last $item
    echo var_export($item, true);
}
```