# Get key of the last element in an array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

Hay, i have an array which contains a set of arrays, here's an example.

```
array(
    [0]=>array('name'=>'bob'),
    [2]=>array('name'=>'tom'),
    [3]=array('name'=>'mark')
)
```

How would i get the last item in the array, and returns it's key.

So in the above example it would return 3.

Comment: what about `count($array);` ^^

Comment: @yes123 this won't work if the keys are numerical and in exact order, without any missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last key in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348205/how-to-get-last-key-in-an-array)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
end($array);
echo key($array)
```

This should return the key of the last element.

Comment: in this solution the pointer of the array is modified to the last position of the array

Answer (score 14):

Try `$lastKey = end(array_keys($array));`

Comment: @yes123 And? It still works, and it's all in one line which is nice.

Comment: I don't want to be overly pedantic, but this will give a `Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference ...` message.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$a = array(
    0=>array('name'=>'bob'),
    2=>array('name'=>'tom'),
    3=>array('name'=>'mark')
);


$b = array_keys($a);
echo end($b);

?>
```

something like this

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
$last_key = key(array_slice($array, -1, true));
```

Comment: This won't preserve keys, which is probably a requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create function and use it:

```
function endKey($array){
end($array);
return key($array);
}

$array = array("one" => "apple", "two" => "orange", "three" => "pear");
echo endKey($array);
```