# How to get the exact value of the last array index in PHP?

Tags: php

Currently i have an array `$newArr` with some elements as shown in picture below. How do I know the last digit of the array index (highlighted in yellow)?

[image]

This is important because, if later I wanted to insert a new record into this `$newArr` array, I could just

```
$newArr[$the_variable_that_holds_the_last_digit + 1] = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

otherwise the whole array overwrite if

```
$newArr = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

Comment: http://php.net/end

Comment: you can use end method

Comment: Many answers had been given. I just want to add that if you want to add a value at the end of your array, you can just do `$newArr[] = ['foo', 'bar'];` or `array_push($newArr, ['foo', 'bar']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [end](http://php.net/end) pointer

```
$array = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3, 
);

end($array);         // it will point to last key
$key = key($array); // get the last key using `key`
```

Comment: why does key($newArr) returns 0? It suppose to be 2, no?

Comment: yes, it should return 2 if everything going proper, if you paste my example it will return `$key` = `c`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this

```
$array = end($newArr);

$last_index = key($array);//Its display last key of array
```

For more details, please follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251331/get-key-of-the-last-element-in-an-array).

Comment: `key` will only provide the current key, i.e first, you need to move pointer to last then access the key

Comment: No its not the answer, because the OP wants a key of the last element, NOT the last element. `end()` returns the last element of the array.

Comment: why does key($newArr) returns 0? It suppose to be 2, no?

Comment: @begineeeerrrr When you should only use key($newArr) then this function return current key only but you should use as per my answer then return last key of array.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the numerically indexed array, the last index on your array is :

```
$last_index = count($newArr) -1;
```

if However your keys are not sequential, you can do this:

```
end($newArr);
$last_key = key($newArr);
```

Comment: Not good if your array looks like this: `['0' => ..., '1' => ..., '3' => ...]`.

Comment: Thats why I said `Assuming you have the numerically indexed array`. the solution is for numerical keys only.

Comment: `0,1,3,7` are numeric, they are just NOT consecutive. `count = 4` but `Highest index value = 7`

Comment: OK I edited the answer. Check it out and let me know if that works.

Comment: why does key($newArr) returns 0? It suppose to be 2, no?

Comment: if you call `key($newArray)` without calling `end($newArray)` first then the key of the first array element  (which is `0`) will be returned. You will have to call `end()` to take the pointer of the array to its last element.

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason is to not overwrite the values you can use [] which means add new value.

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
var_dump($arr);

// incorrect way:
$arr = [1,2];
var_dump($arr);

//correct way
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$arr[] = [1,2];
var_dump($arr);
```

See here for output: https://3v4l.org/ZTg28

The "correct way" will in the example above input a new array in the array.
If you want to add only the values you need to insert them one at the time.

```
$arr[] = 1;
$arr[] = 2;
```