# php array last index

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get last key in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348205/how-to-get-last-key-in-an-array)

I have an array

```
$arr=Array
  (
   [0] = Array
       (
           [groupid] = 1
           [groupname] = Oxy
           [members] = Array
               (
                   [0] = Array
                       (
                           [id] = 9
                           [name] =&gt; Anith
                       )

                   [1] = Array
                       (
                           [id] = 12
                           [name] = sanjay
                       )

                   [3] =Array
                       (
                           [id] = 13
                           [name] = Sooraj K
                       )

               )

       ) )
```

Here `$arr[0]['members'][2]` is unsetted. I want to find the last index of `$arr[0]['members']` here that is 3..how can i find this last index

Comment: What do you mean by last index ???  can you add your expected output

Comment: i need to get the answer 3 here

Answer (score 4):

```
$last = end($arr[0]['members']);
```

Comment: `end()` returns value, not key.

Comment: It returns the last element in an array. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Comment: Yep, and it will be an array(id, name), while Sanu Saji requires key value (3).

Comment: SHOWS AN ERROR  Unsupported operand types

Comment: $key = key(array_reverse($arr['0']['members'], true));

Comment: The code directly above works.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
end($arr[0]["members"]);
$key = key($arr[0]["members"]);
```

It will return you 3.

Comment: can you provide the code you just applied. and also the array.

Comment: i tried the above code with your given array, the --$key-- gives me the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply count the array, i.e

```
$count = count($arr[0]['members']);
```

This will give total number of index. Then to fetch it, you can go like

```
$last_array = $arr[0]['members'][$count-1];
```

I also suggest to also check that it is greater that 0 or not.

Answer (score -2):

Do like :

```
<?php

$arr_keys = array_keys($arr[0]['members']);
$last_index = $arr_keys[count($arr_keys)-1];

?>
```

Comment: `$last_index = end($arr_keys);`?

Answer (score -2):

`$last = max(array_keys($arr[0]['members']));`

Of course, this means sorted array.

Comment: and contiguous, and with a base of 1 (while PHP uses a default of 0)