# PHP: Last key of Object

Tags: php, json, object

I know that some array functions, such as array_rand, work for objects as long as you put (array) in front of the object.  In this case I am trying to get the ID of the

```
 $this->id = end($this->log->r);
```

this returns all of the elements in the last element.  I just want to know what the key of that element is.  This is a JSON_decoded object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last key in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348205/how-to-get-last-key-in-an-array)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`end()` sets the pointer to the last property defined in the object and returns its value.

When the pointer is moved, you can call the `key()` function to get the property name

```
<?php
$object = new stdClass();
$object->first_property = 'first value';
$object->second_property = 'second value';
$object->third_property = 'third value';
$object->last_property = 'last value';

// move pointer to end
end($object);

// get the key
$key = key($object);
var_dump($key);
?>
```

Outputs

`string 'last_property' (length=13)`

This functionality is identical for arrays [How to get last key in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348205/how-to-get-last-key-in-an-array)

Answer (score -2):

You can cast array before apllying end() method on an object :

```
# $menu_items is an object returned by wp_get_nav_menu_items() wordpress method
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('nav_menu');
$last_item = (array) end($menu_items);
print_r($last_item['title']);
```

Comment: This answer was part of my question.  As said there, I know you can do this, I do not want to due to JSON & javascript.