# How to get last array index?

Tags: php

I've found some similar question on StackOverflow, but my problem is different. I'll try to explain more clear possible.
First of all the array structure: `$appointment`

```
Array ( 
  [id_users_provider] => 85  
  [start_datetime] => 2015-11-15 17:15:00  
  [end_datetime] => 2015-11-15 17:15:00  
  [notes] =>  
  [is_unavailable] =>  
  [id_users_customer] => 87  
  [id_services] => 15 
)
Array (  
  [id_users_provider] => 85  
  [start_datetime] => 2015-11-15 17:15:00  
  [end_datetime] => 2015-11-15 17:15:00  
  [notes] =>  
  [is_unavailable] =>  
  [id_users_customer] => 87  
  [id_services] => 13  
)
```

How you can see I've two array included in the `$appointment` variable. Now I want get the end of the last array, in this case the array with `id_services: 13`. I actually execute an iteration through the `appointment['id_services']`. 
Like this:

```
foreach($appointment['id_services'] as $services)
{
   print_r(end($appointment));
}
```

but this return me:

> 15
>   13

and this is wrong, 'cause I want get only `13` in this case. How I can do that?

Comment: see this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348205/how-to-get-last-key-in-an-array could be of help.

Comment: Thanks but as I said I've more array in the same variable so end not working properly in my case.

Comment: You're welcome. I did say *"could be"* ;-)

Comment: is `"SUCCESS"` part of the array too ?

Comment: Oh no sorry, was the response of ajax request that I've inadvertently copied, sorry for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Get the last array index](https://eval.in/469668)

Simply invert the array, then use `end`

```
echo end(array_keys($s));
```

#### [Get all contents of the last array index](https://eval.in/469671)

Simply use `end` through an iteration

```
foreach($appointments as $app) {
   echo end($app) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### [Get only the last element from the sub-array](https://eval.in/469683) (only output 13)

Simply grab the last sub-array and put it through `end`

```
echo end($appointments[ count($appointments) - 1 ]);
```

And if you want to just get `id_services` as you can't guarantee this key will always be last, simply reference it as follows;

```
echo $appointments[ count($appointments) - 1 ]['id_services'];
```

Answer (score 2):

From PHP 7.3 you can use of [array_key_last](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php) function.

```
$last_key = array_key_last($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code assumes that `$services` are only numbers. It iterates over all numbers, checks if the current is greater than `$m` and eventually stores a new `$m`:

```
$m = 0;
foreach($appointment['id_services'] as $services)
    $m = ($services > $m)?$services:$m;

// after the iteration $m has the maximum value
echo $m;
```

**EDIT**: To get the **LAST** (not necessarily the greatest), you could do sth. like this:

```
$c = count($appointment['id_services']);
$l = $appointment['id_services'][$c-1]; // 13
```

Comment: Uhm but how I can check if m is the last value inside the foreach? This is the problem

Comment: See my updated answer, the **LAST** item is stored at `count($array)-1`

Comment: $c and $l should be before $m echo? Could you post the complete code? Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, the first code gets the maximum number while the last code gets the last number. They work independently from each other.

Comment: Oh okay, so I need only the last code. And for check if is the last value? Something like this: if($c < $l) ..?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like this?

```
$appointments=array( 
    array( 'id_users_provider' => 85, 'start_datetime' => '2015-11-15 17:15:00', 'end_datetime' => '2015-11-15 17:15:00', 'notes' => '', 'is_unavailable' => '', 'id_users_customer' => 87, 'id_services' => 15 ),
    array( 'id_users_provider' => 85, 'start_datetime' => '2015-11-15 17:15:00', 'end_datetime' => '2015-11-15 17:15:00', 'notes' => '', 'is_unavailable' =>'', 'id_users_customer' => 87, 'id_services' => 13 )
);

echo $appointments[ count( $appointments )-1 ]['id_services'];
```

Comment: I need to check if the actual $service iteration is the last key

Answer (score 0):

Man, to get last element of an array you do `end($array)`. In your case it's `end($appointments)`. After you get last element, which is in turn a associative array with keys `'id_service'` and so on, you just get the value you need, like `end($appointments)['id_service']`, that's all, what's wrong?