# How do I get the end element of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array (as shown below). It has `a` and `b`, the numbers inside of each of them. However, when I use the `end()` function, it gives me `b`'s array. I want the actual `b` letter. to be printed, not the number array. How can I do this?

```
<?php

$array = array("a" => array(1, 2, 3),
                       "b" => array(4, 5, 6));

$end = end($array);
print_r($end); // gives me 4, 5, 6. I want the value b
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last key in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348205/how-to-get-last-key-in-an-array)

Comment: @Yuri see the duplicate - there are many more solutions there.

Comment: `end($array); then `$end = key($array)`  the call to end puts the internal array pointer at the end of the array, then key gets the key of the current position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `end` with `array_keys` instead:

```
$array = array("a" => array(1, 2, 3),
                       "b" => array(4, 5, 6));
$keys = array_keys($array);
$end = end($keys);
print_r($end);
```

Note that since `end` adjusts the array pointer (hence you can't pass the output from `array_keys` directly to `end` without a notice level error), it's probably preferable to simply use

```
echo $keys[count($keys)-1];
```

Comment: is there a more efficient way of find the last item (i am always looking for b)

Comment: @Cemal yes, it still works in that case. array_keys only gives the keys of the array you pass it. to get the keys of an element of that array which is also an array, you'd have to do something like `array_keys($array['b])`. See https://3v4l.org/EVNLu

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
$array = array("a" => array(1, 2, 3),"b" => array(4, 5, 6));
                
end($array);

echo key($array);
```

Output

```
b
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dcd4064a3a03ea4b9c65a125274bd5d52ee3011e)

the call to `end` puts the internal array pointer at the end of the array, then key gets the `key` of the current position (which is now the last item in the array).

To reset the array pointer just use:

```
 reset($array); //moves pointer to the start
```

You cant do it in one line, because end returns the array element at the `end` and `key` needs the array as it's argument.  It's a bit "Weird" because `end` moves the internal array pointer, which you don't really see.

### Update

One way I just thought of that is one line, is to use array reverse and key:

```
 echo key(array_reverse($array));
```

Basically when you do `array_reverse` it flips the order around and returns the reversed array.  We can then use this array as the argument for `key()`, which gets the (current) first key of our now backwards array, or the last key of the original array(sort of a double negative).

Output

```
 b
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5221c7eb89ee4b13b8f9cbed48fda691f9dd1b14)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to loop through the keys of the array and store the key at each index.

```
<?php

$array = array("a" => array(1, 2, 3),
"b" => array(4, 5, 6));

foreach ($array as $key => $value) $end = $key;
// This will overwrite the value until you get to the last index then print it out

print_r($end);
```