# i want to access the last key and value how it is possible?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Array
(
    [states] => Array
        (
            [] => Select State
            [1] => Andaman and Nicobar (AN)
            [2] => Andhra Pradesh (AP)
            [3] => Arunachal Pradesh (AR)
            [4] => Assam (AS)
            [5] => Bihar (BR)
            [6] => Chandigarh (CH)
            [7] => Chhattisgarh (CG)
            [8] => Dadra and Nagar Haveli (DN)
            [9] => Daman and Diu (DD)
            [10] => Delhi (DL)
            [11] => Goa (GA)
            [12] => Gujarat (GJ)
            [13] => Haryana (HR)
            [14] => Himachal Pradesh (HP)
            [15] => Jammu and Kashmir (JK)
            [16] => Jharkhand (JH)
            [17] => Karnataka (KA)
            [18] => Kerala (KL)
            [19] => Lakshdweep (LD)
            [20] => Madhya Pradesh (MP)
            [21] => Maharashtra (MH)
            [22] => Manipur (MN)
            [23] => Meghalaya (ML)
            [24] => Mizoram (MZ)
            [25] => Nagaland (NL)
            [26] => Odisha (OD)
            [27] => Puducherry (PY)
            [28] => Punjab (PB)
            [29] => Rajasthan (RJ)
            [30] => Sikkim (SK)
            [31] => Tamil Nadu (TN)
            [32] => Telangana (TG)
            [33] => Tripura (TR) 
            [34] => Uttar Pradesh (UP)
            [35] => Uttarakhand (UK)
            [36] => West Bengal (WB)
        )

```
[captcha_image] => 
[browser_details] => Chrome
[browser_version] => 75.0.3770.100
[user_ip_address] => ::1
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[11] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[12] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[13] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[14] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[15] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[16] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[17] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[18] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[19] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[20] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[21] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[22] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[23] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[24] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[25] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[26] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[27] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[28] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 2019-07-08 15:14:38
    )
```

)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last key in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348205/how-to-get-last-key-in-an-array)

Comment: Please provide proper indentation of your sample input. Also, what is the expected output? What have you tried(although this question has lost it's value)?

Answer (score 1):

**1-** **i want to access the last key and value how it is possible?**

```
<?php
    //Append the array value in variable $array, After that follow the below step.
      end($array['states']); // The end() function moves the internal pointer to, and outputs, the last element in the array.

        $key = key($array['states']);  // get the last key
        echo $value = $array['states'][$key]; // get last value be key
        ?>
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/4NIEG)

**2- Ans based on comments 'how can i access each value particularly of object array?'**

```
//Append your object_array in variable call array
$array = object_array; 
//Using loop you can get the value of object. 
foreach ($array as $value) { 
echo $value->date_added ; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Bt I do not want to use end function because it gives me the access of last index.. I want to access the all the stdclass  objects ohk

Comment: In Question you mention i want to access the last key and value how it is possible?

Comment: Yess but also want that how? Sorry for my mistake

Comment: I think you talking about second object array. i'm right?

Comment: [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )   form till last how can i access each value particularly?

Comment: For this you have need to use foreach loop to get the value - like $array = object_array;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value->date_added ;
}

Comment: Now you are getting the object value.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 end($array['states']);
 $z = prev($array['states']);
```