# "Call to undefined function array_key_last()" although it is a PHP function that works locally

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, php-7.3

I made a website that works perfectly locally.
Now I'm trying to publish it online with ploi.io .
I get this error:

> "Call to undefined function array_key_last()" 
>   3rd line in code

but `array_key_last()` is a PHP-function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php

Here is my website link: http://rocallisa.xyz/

```
if($key === array_key_last($photos))
```

My server is running `PHP 7.3` but this doesn't help.

Comment: PHP Version running on your Server is different from what is running in your local. My guess is that Server is not running PHP 7

Comment: I suppose your server is not php7.3. Run `phpinfo()` and see.

Comment: It says my server is running php 7.3

Answer (score 3):

What is the PHP version in the online publication?

In PHP docs:

> array_key_last (PHP 7 >= 7.3.0)

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-last.php

Is the version of your remote server latter than 7.3?

An alternative:
[How to get last key in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348205/how-to-get-last-key-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to php-7.3, a possible way inline.

```
$a = (object)["some"=>5, "stuffs"=>3];
echo @end(array_keys( $a ));
// "stuffs"
```

Notice the error control operator, because `end()`, or use an intermediary variable.

```
PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference
```

⚠ The gain in performance and memory footprint is huge using `array_key_last()` and `array_key_first()`, consider upgrading to php7.4.